Horror movie about a family in a forest escaping a plague
I'm looking for a movie that takes place in an apocalyptic scene. There is a disease that is spreading that causes people to go absolutely insane, but without knowing it.
A family is trying to survive through this but they soon die off through the movie, and it is revealed at the end that the dad had this disease and killed his whole family. He then kills himself for what he has done.
A few more things I remember are that the majority of the movie took place in a forest. The movie started with the family going into an empty gas station for supplies. I also vaguely remember gas masks being used to prevent the disease, or something like that.
Almost certainly from the last decade. Also for sure in English, the movie was pretty low budget and only had at most 15-20 people in it.

Hi. Are you the same person who asked this?

I did not ask that question, but that is definitely the movie I am talking about.

So was it right in saying the movie is from the last decade? Was it in English?

Yes, almost certain in the last decade. Also for sure in English, the movie was pretty low budget and only had at most 15-20 people in it.

You're looking for The Collapsed from 2011.

In the wake of the end of the world, a family of four desperately tries to survive against insurmountable odds. Their goal: escaping the city and traveling to the rural community they once called home, Dover's Bend. The constant threat of a violent death forcing them to stay as far away from civilization as possible, they take to the forest, soon to discover the danger posed by other survivors may be the least of their worries.

It ends like you described: The father has amnesia and actually imagined it after killing his family. Here's the trailer:



